# Using TCPClient() with IP:PORT/PATH

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, tcpclient

I need to manually develop a SOAP communication in C# to consume some Java web services using SSL.

I was looking at a tutorial online and like many other tutorials it connects to the endpoint using:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, port);
```

But I need to connect to something like this `192.168.0.1:8201/some/path` and I can't seem to find a way to specify the path. Also looked at `IPEndpoint` but also no luck there

Comment: I strongly doubt you want to do this using TcpClient. The "path" in this space is a layer up from TCP - implemented within the web service layer.

Comment: You are probably right. Maybe I need to check this again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` instead. For ex,

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] buf  = wc.DownloadData("https://192.168.0.1:8201/some/path");
//or
string s =  wc.DownloadString("https://192.168.0.1:8201/some/path");
```

You can also use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) and try to add a `service reference` to your project

Comment: I also need to send some data. The reason I'm not importing the services is that somehow the (possibly deprecated) wsdl that is provided comes from a PDF file (yes really a WSDL shared in a PDF file). Also the generated client doesn't seem to be anything like it's supposed to be.

Comment: Using a `WebClient` and `Uploaddata` I got this working. Thanks for your help